how to use encrypted properties kafka-ui
I want to encrypt secrets that are passed to kafka-ui. Does provectus (https://github.com/provectus/kafka-ui) or kafbat (https://github.com/kafbat/kafka-ui) kafka-ui support encrypted properties out of the box?  I looked the code to see if they are using jasypt or spring-cloud encryption but I don't see them in pom file.
